# Maven clean install failure (unable to access url via browser)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I searched the forum before asking but I'm currently unable to find an answer.

I installed Maven and met problem trying to do the clean install.
You'll find below the POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Sopra.sourcing</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-sourcing</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-sourcing</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> 
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
     <version>2.37.0</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

The error I get is *Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing, no dependency information available.*

When I try to see this this url in my browser, I get nothing, so there's a big problem.
I've spent the day on that thing (not an experienced developper), anyone here has an idea of the problem ?

Thanks, any help much appreciated ;-)

Comment: Behind a proxy? Sounds like this.

Comment: Yes, I'm behind a proxy. I configured it before to finish the install so that Maven could upgrade itself.
So I'm not sure it's a proxy problem, or it is a big one, because I can't even access the url with my browser.

Comment: Clean your local repository and retry the build. If everything is downloaded correctly everything works otherwise you have a problem with your proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I tried to add it but it didn't work. Do you have other ideas ?